# Eating rhubarb after it's bolted

Tags: food-crops, rhubarb, bolting

I had a surprise rhubarb plant pop up 2 years after moving into my house, and was looking forward to harvesting it until it started flowering.

[image: my rhubarb plant showing a bud]
[image: my rhubarb plant showing a flower]

I've heard that bolting can affect the taste of lettuce for the worse (though I've never tested that theory.) Is the same true for rhubarb? And if it is a problem, what should I do next year if I see a flower developing?

Comment: +1 for showing me a new thing. Never seen rhubarb flower.

Comment: Normally the flower stalks are removed . they draw nutrients from the plant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall any significant detriment to the flavor of rhubarb from bolting - rhubarb is not lettuce. Most lettuce does turn more bitter when flowering. Last I sampled my bolting kale (from which I'm trying to get seeds, so I'm happy to have it bolt)  it was still fine, but I haven't checked *that* in a few weeks. (*Update - my kale is still edible - perhaps a slight impact on the flavor.)*

*I mean, it's possible the leaves may change, but since eating rhubarb leaves is toxic to people anyway, not a change in flavor I'd notice, as I'm not eating them in any case.*

You can just cut the flower stalk off (now, or as soon as you notice it next year,) unless you happen to be interested in seeing it flower.